# Typo3 Listview buttons inactive

Tags: typo3

i am using the dam_frontend 0.6.6 extension for my local TYPO3 4.7.7 and i have some problems with the listview.

I created a new content on my site and put the extensions plugin in it. Inside the plugin, i choose the option "Listview". So the file list shows me all the files and documents that "a user" has been uploaded.

Furthermore, the file view has two buttons, once a magnifying glass (as a view of the file) and a download button. Unfortunately, when i click one of this buttons, nothing happens. 
How can I activate these buttons?

I would like to upload an image but i have a new account and first of all i have to do 10 reputations to poste an image -.-

Code in the extension setup:

```
link_download = IMAGE
    link_download {
        file = EXT:dam_frontend/res/ico/clip_pasteafter.gif
        #style="border-width: 0px
        stdWrap.typolink {
            parameter.data = TSFE:id


            additionalParams = &eID=dam_frontend_push&docID={field:uid}
            additionalParams.insertData = 1
        }
        if.value=1
        if.equals.field=allowDownload
    }

    link_single = IMAGE
    link_single {
        file = EXT:dam_frontend/res/ico/zoom.gif
        #style="border-width: 0px
        stdWrap.typolink {
            parameter.data = TSFE:id
            additionalParams = &tx_damfrontend_pi1[showUid]={field:uid}&tx_damfrontend_pi1[backPid]={TSFE:id}
            additionalParams.insertData = 1
            no_cache  = 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share some code, showing what you have done. Maybe event a screenshot, to illustrate the problem.

Comment: sorry i am new here and i dont know where i can upload an image :P.... in my frontend there is List View (from the extension) and it shows the title, filetyp, date, autor, language and at least the two buttons. The extentsion template (Part of the Listview):

Comment: You can edit your original question to contain the code.

Comment: i need 10 reputation to post images -.-